# Oozie Simple Authentication

Tags: authentication, oozie

Just getting started with oozie, using a simple test class (not the client) and webservices, but running into authentication problems. I believe the server is set up to do simple authentication (inherited these configs).

```
<property>
  <name>oozie.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>oozie.authentication.type</name>
  <value>simple</value>
</property>
```

But I'm unsure how the authorization is supposed to work. Under /etc/conf/adminusers.text, there is the user "oozie". From the [documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/AG_Install.html#Oozie_User_Authentication_Configuration), it appears that I'm supposed to pass "user.name" as part of the request. Attempting to pass it as part of the XML results in a 401 error, as does adding `user.name=oozie` to the query string.

```
public void submitJob(String xmlJob) throws IOException {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(HADOOP_CON_MGR);

    String url = getJobsUrl();
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);
    method.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(xmlJob, "application/xml", "UTF-8"));
    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            new OozieClient().submitJob("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
            "<configuration><property><name>user.name</name><value>oozie</value></property>" + 
            "<property><name>oozie.wf.application.path</name>" +
            "<value>hdfs://10.1.2.88:50700/user/guest</value></property></configuration>"
             );
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: User "oozie" runs the Oozie service; but jobs are supposed to be run under the user that submitted them (each user may have specific HDFS privileges, specific Hive privileges, specific YARN scheduling policies, etc.) Since your cluster allows anonymous access to the Oozie service you should have no issue when running a simple GET request. I'm not sure if (and how) Ozie checks the supplied `user.name` property in a POST, though

Comment: BTW you don't show the actual URL you use for that POST: which version of Oozie and which version of the API are you using, to begin with? cf. for example http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/WebServicesAPI.html#Oozie_Web_Services_API_V2_Workflow__Coordinator_And_Bundle

Comment: Check out this article: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/06/how-to-use-the-apache-oozie-rest-api/

- it didn't actually solve this problem for me but maybe it does for you